# Обработчик событий

Tags: php

Как сделать так, чтобы определённое действие выполняло по нажатию по картинке?

Comment: Java Script

Answer (score 3):

```
<img src="_IMG_DIR_" onClick="alert("определённое действие выполняю");" />
```

Answer (score 1):

если вам надо чтото сделать на сервере, то нада отправить AJAX запрос по нажатию на картинку